# Long boolean expression

Tags: javascript, boolean, expression

Why the console shows "2" and "false" in this expressions?

```
var a = '' || 0 || 2 || true || false;
var b = 3 && true && false && null;
console.log (a,b);
```

Comment: This is how `logical operators` work..

Comment: It is duplicated, but I don't understand the downvote, the question is fair and clear

Comment: May be because OP does not seems to have done enough research!

Comment: [`Logical Operators`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators)

Answer (score 1):

You got those results because it's **logical comparison** here, using **logical operators `&&` and `||`**, if you take a look at [MDN Specification of **Logical Operators**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators), you will see that:

> **Logical OR (||)**: Returns expr1 if it can be converted to true; otherwise, returns expr2. Thus, when used with Boolean values, || returns true if either operand can be converted to true; if both can be converted to false, returns false.
>
> **Logical AND (&&)**: Returns expr1 if it can be converted to false; otherwise, returns expr2. Thus, when used with Boolean values, && returns true if both operands can be converted to true; otherwise, returns false.

So in your case:

For the first expression:

```
var a = '' || 0 || 2 || true || false;
```

It will return `2` because it's the first oprand that's evaluated to `true`.

And for the second one:

```
var b = 3 && true && false && null;
```

It will return `false` as one of its operand is `false`.

Comment: You are welcome, just dive a little more into it and you will see everything.